# Swift 3 Button in UICollectionViewCell not respond to touch

Tags: uicollectionview, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have an `UICollectionViewCell` and two buttons inside that, but the buttons not respond to touch, i create button programmatically and add that to cell by `addSubView` it works, but when i added by holder.`addSubView` not working!

`UserInteractionEnabeld` of holder is true!

help please

```
class FavoriteProductCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var holder: UIView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let btnFindBestPrice = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 151, height: 20))



        btnFindBestPrice.setTitle("Find best price", for: .normal)
        btnFindBestPrice.backgroundColor = UIColor.ButtonBackGreen

        btnFindBestPrice.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        btnFindBestPrice.addTarget(self, action: #selector(findBestPrice), for: .touchUpInside)

        // AddTarget not working
        holder.addSubview(btnFindBestPrice)


        // AddTarget works fine
        addSubview(btnFindBestPrice)
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if `holder.isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to true. Also, check that `holder` is big enough. Could you set its backgroundColor to red/green or whatever and check that the button isn't too big for it? I got this case recently. Button was visible, but superview (in your case `holder`) was too small, causing touch to be ignored.

Comment: share the UI how you want to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why!? But i create another cell with same config that worked fine!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's better if you add `self` at the beginning. Like this:

```
self.holder.addSubview(btnFindBestPrice)
```